# how to use a placeholder syntax for pattern matching using like operator in PostgreSQL with Spring Data JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, sql-like

I am using Spring Data JPA with postgresql as data base.Want to search a pattern using user given keyword

```
@Query(value = "SELCET * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE (CONCAT('%',:pattern,'%'))")       
List<Class> findPattern(String pattern);
```

but :pattern is not replacing with pattern value

Answer (score 0):

You may try binding the entire `LIKE` expression to a single placeholder:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE :pattern")
List<Object[]> findPattern(String pattern);
```

The usage would be something like this:

```java
String value = "blah";
String pattern = "%" + value + "%";
List<Object[]> rs = repo.findPattern(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `like %pattern%` is the same as *contains* pattern, your use case doesn't even need a query coded:

```
List<MyClass> findByColumnNameContaining(String pattern);
```

Comment: but column name is not known, have to perform pattern matching with multiple columns inside the query